# Как в многомерный массив положить другой массив?

Tags: c

Как в многомерный массив положить другой массив? Почему мой код не работает?

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int     *ft_range(int min, int max)
{
    int *arr;
    int i;

    i = 0;
    if (!(min < max) || !(arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (max - min))))
    {
        return (0);
    }
    while (min < max)
    {
        arr[i++] = min++;
    }
    return (arr);
}

int     main()
{   
    int* man;
    int* man1;
    int** superman;

    man = ft_range(0, 30);
    man1 = ft_range(0, 30);

    superman[0] = man;
    superman[1] = man1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int** superman;

man = ft_range(0, 30);
man1 = ft_range(0, 30);

superman = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * 2);
superman[0] = man;
superman[1] = man1;
```

Comment: Подскажите, а почему без malloc не работает?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Давайте перефразируем: "Почему не работает, когда я пытаюсь писать в память, которую не выделил?"

Comment: @Igor я бы сказал которой нет, malloc ничего не выделяет, это же не sbrk